# Detect user arrival using BLE

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon

I'm a student and have never worked with BLE devices. Assuming there's a BLE sensor, how can the BLE sensor detect a user's arrival when the user come close to the BLE sensor? The idea is to detect a user's arrival using a BLE sensor and then look up the user's record in the database. The user is supposed to use an android app and would need to register for an account beforehand.

I was thinking to to use the user's phone number as a primary key in the database, so when the user approaches the BLE sensor, something needs to happen between the BLE sensor and the android app notifying the system that a user has arrived and their record needs to be searched in the database. I don't understand how to solve the part where the BLE sensor needs to detect the user.

Comment: This is maybe not specific about a programming issue to be on topic for SO. There should be plenty of information out there on this topic. For example: https://medium.com/supplyframe-hardware/bluetooth-indoor-positioning-and-asset-tracking-solutions-8c78cae0a03 and https://www.beaconzone.co.uk/blog/bluetooth-beacon-based-student-registration-system/

Answer (score 0):

This should be doable using Bluetooth with the caveats that it will require a lot of work (given that you have no worked on BLE before) and that you won't be able to tell the distance - just that the user is "within range".

To achieve this, you first need a scanner app that is **constantly scanning for a certain "service"**. This scanner app should be sitting on a constantly powered device. You can use any development kit or programmable BLE device for this. Some recommendations include a Raspberry Pi or a ESP32.

Then you need an Android app that is constantly **advertising a certain "service"**. The Android app needs to be working in the background mode and the user needs to give it all the permission needed to allow it to be constantly advertising.

Back to the scanner part. The way to add the user to the database is by the scanner device connecting and exchanging information with the advertising Android device. This is not a necessary step as you can change information via the BLE adverts. However a connection might make things quicker and simpler in my opinion. Upon connection, the scanner device should request a certain ID from the Android app. Ideally, this ID would've been distributed from the database upon an initiation procedure  when the scanner was set up the first time. The reason I am suggesting this instead of a phone number is that you can't use a phone number for privacy and tracking reasons. Additionally, having a setup/initiation phase where the user has to get an ID from the database adds a level of consent.

So going back over what is needed:-

1. A scanner app sitting on a constantly powered device (e.g. Raspberry Pi).
2. The scanner app is constantly scanning for devices with a certain BLE service (e.g. 0xFE99 - see the links below for more details about BLE services).
3. The scanner app will have access to a database.
4. An advertiser app on an Android device that is constantly advertising in the background.
5. There needs to be an initiation phase where the Android app connects to the scanner, sends the scanner the user details (e.g. name and email), and the scanner gives the app a key from its database (internally, the scanner associates the name and email with the sent key).
6. The Android app stores the key.
7. In the future, when the scanner detects that the Android app is within range, it will request to connect to it and request the stored key.
8. The Android app should accept the connection in the background and send the key.
9. The scanner app associates the key to the person and the database is updated.

Have a look at the links below to help you get started on the various bits and pieces that are needed to accomplish something like this:-

- [A complete guide to BLE beacon technology](https://blog.beaconstac.com/2018/08/ble-made-simple-a-complete-guide-to-ble-bluetooth-beacons/)
- [Getting started with BLE](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/getting-started-with/9781491900550/ch01.html)
- [Bluetooth Low Energy: A primer](https://interrupt.memfault.com/blog/bluetooth-low-energy-a-primer)
- [How to advertise Android as a BLE peripheral](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-advertise-android-as-a-bluetooth-le-peripheral--cms-25426)
- [How to set up Bluetooth on a Raspberry Pi](https://howchoo.com/pi/bluetooth-raspberry-pi)